# Compare a group of characters with a string C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, compare, character

I have a 2D vector that is holding characters for a word search game.  I have to take a string (the word I'm searching for) and go through the whole list to compare the string and a group of characters to see if they match and output where I found the match in the 2D vector.  I am just confused on how to go about the comparison of strings and a group of characters.

This is the bit that I started trying to compare:

```
bool SearchWord::SolveRowsRight(int index)
{
    string findWord = GetWord(index);
    for(int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < board.size() - findWord.size(); j++)
        {
            if(findWord == board[i][j])
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting errors? What are they?

Comment: It'd help to explain what part you're confused about. For example, I see your code will say it's a match if the first letter matches, you may want to reverse your logic and check for non matching.

Comment: Since I am comparing characters and strings the 'findWord == board[i][j])' doesn't work but I don't know what else to put. Operand types are: std::string == char

Comment: @jsnaredude Try `if (findWord == board[i])`.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what your code is supposed to do, but maybe that'll help: If you have a `std::string` and a `char*` (or a `char[]`) you can compare them letter-by-letter using `strncmp( yourString.c_str(), yourCharArrayOrPointer, numberOfLettersToCompare )`. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/

Comment: I got what I needed. I wasn't aware you could take one character form a string to compare so just 'findWord[j]' is all I needed. Thank you!